# Ctrl character is coming at using of paste command

Tags: shell

When i am using paste command to join two files then ^M character is coming at the join time in output file. How can i remove this without using another command(sed,tr)?

I just want to confirm that there is any way in which I can paste the files with ^M character.

Answer (score 0):

ctrl-M is a carriage return: your file has DOS line endings. Try using `dos2unix` on your files first. I don't think that `paste` by itself can do anything about it.